# Responsive thumbnails - shrink up to a point and restore hiding one

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, autoresize

I have been trying to code a responsive thumbnail group that I'd like it to respect to a few rules.

I came very close but the implementation always end up not satisfying at least one of the rules. In other words when I try to do one thing it always cancels the other.

In summary, what I am trying to achieve is something like this -

http://postimg.org/image/4yx6poscz/f57d6517/ (I wasn't allowed to post a picture, sorry)

So basically, what I am after is;

When the user resizes the window the thumbnails (consist of an image and some basic HTML) will shrink up to a point.

When the breakpoint is reached, the most left one will disappear and the rest of the thumbnails will return to their original size.

Continue until the min-body size where we just display the x-axis scrollbar.

So, referring to the image, providing that no resizing is done just yet, the items will shrink, lets say until 20% and then Item 7 will disappear letting free space to the rest of the row to expand to their original size.

I am currently using the latest version of bootstrap however, as you may guess col-lg col-md and etc. classes are not really helpful in this case. I have come up with some custom breakpoints but I can't get my head around the shrinking back to the original size issue. That is where I get stuck.

Also I think it's worth mentioning that Ive been trying to come up with a solution that is pure HTML and CSS however I am definitely open to JS solutions as well.

A good example would be spotify's webplayer (play.spotify.com) thumbnail examples.

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you add code in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, my thumbnails are something along the lines of; http://jsfiddle.net/g7x2ezLu/ Although the problem is, when I have a fixed sized for the thumbnail container then the resizing doesn't happen, however I need them to be a fixed size. Not sure if that makes sense? @youngshot

Comment: @youngshot You can remove 180x180 size constraint to observe the change, thanks